# How to combine content from two different environments?

Tags: nodes, staging

We have two Drupal environments: dev and prod.  We use dev to stage content before it goes to production.  We also have prod, where content is created and then have to manually re-create those changes back on dev.

Is there a way to combine/merge content changes between the two environments simply/easily?  This is purely content (i.e. nodes) and not code or configuration.

Answer (score 1):

## Node Export

The [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module might be used for this. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> This module allows users to export nodes and then import it into another Drupal installation, or on the same site.
>
> Using this module you can save yourself a lot of time setting up new websites that have similar nodes to websites you've already made, migrating nodes to new Drupal versions, or between development/staging/production sites.
>
> You will need the same content types for the imports to work (unless using Feeds to import), and ideally relevant compatibility with fields, and modules.

## Feeds

Another option that might work is to use the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.

## Bundle copy

Yet another approach is to use the [Bundle copy](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Has export/import support for:
>
> - Node types
> - Taxonomy
> - User
> - Field API fields
> - Field groups
>
> You can find the export/import links for the supported entities on following paths:
>
> - Nodes: admin/structure/types
> - Taxonomy: admin/structure/taxonomy
> - Users: admin/config/people/accounts

Answer (score 1):

You may also try [Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) module

> The Deploy module is designed to allow users to easily stage content from one Drupal site to another. Deploy automatically manages dependencies between entities (like node references). It is designed to have a rich API which can be easily extended to be used in a variety of content staging situations.